# What's the probability of the game being cancelled due to players not showing up

Tags: probability

> There are two teams, and each team has 6 players. 4 players are required for the game to go on. The probability of a player not showing up is $10\%$.
> What's the probability of the game being cancelled?

#### My approach

The probability of someone showing up is $9/10$ so I multiplied $9/10 \cdot 9/10 \cdot 9/10\cdot 9/10$ which gave me $65.6\%$ chance of $4$ people showing up. And squared that to make it up for two teams. I ended up getting $43\%$ chance of the match going, which sounds very low given the $1/10$ chance of someone not showing up. And I can't seem to think of any other ways to calculate this.

Comment: Do you know [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)?

Comment: Include that information (your current thoughts/approach) in the original post of the question and you will have a much better response from the users here.  It is a general rule that all questions should include information about what you have tried or what specifically you don't understand so that we can know how to help you.  As for your actual question, as Fundamental mentions, consider a binomial distribution on each team separately to find the probability of a single team having at least 4 members.

Comment: does that involve permutation and combination?
p.s. thank you JMoravitz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The success probability of one trial is $p=9/10$, and you need $\ge 4$ successes in $6$ trials for the  team to qualify. One way to find the probability of this happening is to add the probabilities of exactly $4,5,6$ successes to find that. According to [binomial distribution formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) this is 
$$\binom{6}{4}p^4(1-p)^2+ \binom{6}{5}p^5(1-p)+\binom{6}{6}p^6$$
giving the probability for one team. Then square to account for two teams, as you did.

---

The error in your approach can be explained as follows. Say, the team has six players ABCDEF. Then $(9/10)^4$ represents the probability of four *particular* players showing up, for example ABCD. But you don't need ABCD specifically to show up, it can be any four. Hence, some summation is involved, as above.

Comment: Thanks a lot Fundamental.
The answer makes sense but why binomial distribution would be the best way to do this seems a bit abstract to me. Would you care to tell me why using binomial distribution is the best option?

Comment: You have 6 independent "trials" (each player showing up or not), and are interested in having at least 4 "successes" (4 showing up). This is precisely the task that the binomial distribution is made for. The reason the $\binom{6}{k}$ show up is that they represent the number of possibilities for exactly $k$ players to appear out of $6$.

Comment: Perfect. Appreciate your help!

Comment: question, 

So the probability of a particular player showing up is an independent event ? That is to say if one player shows up then p = 9/10 remains the same?

Comment: @stuntstool Although independence wasn't explicitly stated in the problem, this is the only reasonable interpretation of the statement.